# how to access a variable from a .py script in another .py script

Tags: python

I need to get the updated value of a variable(ex: results) , which is set in the main() function  of a first.py script in the  second.py script!

**first.py**

```
def main():
    results = os.path.abspath(r'D:\results')
    return 0
```

**second.py**

```
-> need to access results here
```

Any help highly appreciated?

Comment: Something like this, but bear in mind you are returning `0`, not `result_path` - `from first import main; var = main()`. If you need to access multiple variables inside the function, you could use a class instead and set them as attributes (`from first import Main; cls = Main(); var = cls.result_path`).

Comment: ``results`` is only known within the scope of ``main()``, you cannot access it from anywhere else, not even from ``first.py``.

Comment: You might want to start using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) that allows you to save and load python objects to/from disk

Answer (score 0):

You will need a function, which will then be imported, like:

```
from example.py import func()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the file **second.py**

```
import first as f

main = f.main()
result = main.result_path
```

Please try this. I hope it helps a bit.

Comment: ``main`` will be the int value ``0``, so you're trying to access ``0.result_path``, which will fail.

Comment: in this case adjust 'main()' to return result_path. I was more trying to access the variable in the second file and not to correct his first file. For me, as long he can access the file in the second path, the question should be answered. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your first script in your second and additionally set result_path as a global variable.

`first.py`:

```
result_path = None

def main():
    global result_path
    result_path = os.path.abspath(r'D:\results')
```

`second.py`:

```
import first

access = first.result_path
```

You could also define a method in `first.py`, that just returns `result_path` and then call it in `second.py`, but therefor you'd still need to set `result_path` global.

Comment: Hi AracKnight Thanks ! this solution works .  But currently i am facing another problem .  Currently i changed my logic to update the 'result_path' variable  dynamically based on the execution of first.py (not a hardcoded path i mean) , in that case I am unable to fetch it in second.py  script now !  Stuck again                                    i am calling first.py in second.py using subprocess.popen ()

Answer (score 0):

This will work

**First.py**

```
def main():
    results = os.path.abspath(r'D:\results')
    return results
```

**second.py**

```
from First import main
resultsHere = main()
```